# Expectation of $x^n$ when $x$~$U[0,1]$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, expected-value, auction-theory

I'm trying to follow along with my textbook on Auction Theory, but don't understand one of the steps. I don't see how they got $E[x^N] = 1/(N+1)$ in the final step. Please see the linked image below. Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks so much! 
[Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oo4D3.png)

Answer (score 2):

Note:

$$E(X^n)=\int_0^1 t^n \ dt$$